# How to change a ARO parent in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, acl

I am having trouble updating the aros table in my CakePHP app.  Here is the code I've got:

```
$aro = new Aro();
$targetAro = $aro->find('first', array('conditions' => array('foreign_key' => intval($user['User']['id']))));
$newParent = $aro->find('first', array('conditions' => array('alias' => $userUpdate->level)));
$targetAro['Aro']['parent_id'] = $newParent['Aro']['id'];
$aro->updateAll($targetAro);
```

I've put in debug log statements to make sure that I'm getting the correct results from the find calls.  But when I check the database after the updateAll call, the data is unchanged.  Any ideas what might be going on?

I also tried calling $aro->setParent but I couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by tracing through the code that does a similar thing in the cake console.  Instead of using $aro->updateAll($targetAro) I should be using **$aro->saveAll($targetAro)**.

updateAll() is used to save changes to a number of entities.  The first argument should be an array of values.  saveAll() is used when you just want to save the changes to a single entity, as is the case in the code above.

Althought it seems like I should, I couldn't find error output anywhere in the logs or the script output because of the incorrect arguments I was passing to updateAll().